# What's the name of this process?

Tags: terminology, definition, roots

What's the name of this process?   $$\sqrt{50} \to 5\sqrt2$$
Can you tell me its name?

Comment: Surd simplification?

Comment: Factoring is another possibility

Comment: There's no need to tart up a simple equality with `→`; Good ol' `=` is more accurate.

Comment: @ryang The process being described here is not symmetric, and the question is not about the claim of equality. For instance, the process of "put as much under the square root symbol as you can" would be the opposite process.  $\to$ is much more appropriate to show that idea than $=$ which has a symmetric and declarative meaning.

Comment: `x = sqrt(50) <-> x = 5 sqrt(2)` would be the implicative form

Comment: @MarkS. I see. Okay, if the OP intends their `→` to connect an expression and  the result of performing some operation on it, then maybe `↦` or `⟶` better than what currently looks like the logical conditional.

Comment: Based on the german naming for this ("teilweises Radizieren") I suggest "partially taking roots".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process is called surd simplification. Barry Carter in the comments said that this is called factoring. Factorisation is a form of simplification, where we reduce a mathematical object to the product of two (or more) factors. I suppose you can think of this as factorising, since you are expressing $\sqrt 50$  as a product of $5$ and $\sqrt2$. However, in most of the textbooks I have used, the term surd *simplification* is preferred. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have never heard this term.   I don't like it. It may be in use in schools somewhere, but never by mathematicians. Who's to say which of those two equal expressions is "simpler"? In any particular context you may prefer one or the other.

Comment: @EthanBolker True. However, the user seems to be in school given his knowledge, so I gave him a school - level answer

Comment: That's fair enough.

Comment: @EthanBolker I do understand your point however. Also, I'm in school too! I'm 14.

Comment: You have lots of fun mathematics to look forward to. Much more fun than "simplifying".

Comment: @EthanBolker I know! I'm learning undergraduate set theory which is very interesting. I have finished school - level set theory so I decided I would do something a little more juicy.